# properly format HTML inside UILabel

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am fetching HTML content from online web service, I am using UILabel and rendering the HTML inside.

The issue that I am having is that sometimes the images/videos inside are being cut at the end of the screen(because there isn't enough room to display it all), because I am not using scrolling I am flipping into a new element, how can I make sure that images/videos are being cut, meaning I am displaying content properly. If I reached the end of the screen and I have no enough space to add an image I would like the image to go on the other page. Do I solve this programmatically using code? any existing sdk to help, or should I have the server respond with multiple objects each one for 1 element.

Comment: Why don't you use `UIWebView`?